# Raphael.js How to get center point location of paper and scale relative to the center?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have defined my raphael paper like below:

```
var paper = Raphael("my-paper", '100%', '100%');

//render some shapes on my paper
var e = paper.ellipse(50, 50, 40, 20);
var c = paper.circle(50, 50, 40);
var r = paper.rect(40, 40, 50, 50, 10);
```

As you saw above, I defined my Raphael paper, then drew some shapes on my paper. I have following two questions to ask:

**1.** How to get the center point x and y value of my paper. (x: horizontal location, y: vertical location)

**2.** I would like to scale everything on my paper to twice bigger size, I know I can use Raphel [scale function](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#scale). I would like to scale all the elements on the paper **relative to the center of my paper**, so, I need to do something like:

```
e.scale(2, 2, CENTER_X, CENTER_Y)
```

( `CENTER_X` and `CENTER_Y` are asked in **question 1** )

I'd like the result looks like zoom in, am I using in the right way or are there other ways to do it?

Comment: Are you still looking for this answer? I can provide you with a working example...

Answer (score 8):

paper.width and paper.height should return the dimensions of the paper which would give you the center.

Comment: Raphael.fn.paperCenter = function() {
             return { x: this.width/2, y: this.height/2 };
     };

Answer (score 0):

You can find center of the paper  like this

```
var x = this.paper.canvas.offsetLeft;
var y = this.paper.canvas.offsetTop;

var centerX = x + paper.width/2 ;
var centerY=  y + paper.height/2;
```